# AccessDenied Page with incorrect returnUrl for unauthorized user in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, unauthorized, returnurl

I have created a custom /AccessDenied page for unauthorized users with a returnUrl link.

If a user currently present at /ProductList page and want to access /EditProduct page then I am redirecting an unauthorized user to /AccessDenied page with returnUrl, but in returnUrl, I am getting /EditProduct page URL while I want /ProductList page URL.

Because when the user clicks the Link of returnUrl at /AccessDenied page, it redirected to /EditProduct page and then to  /AccessDenied page but it should redirect to /ProductList page.
How this problem can be resolved?

I mentioned the path of /AccessDenied page in a startup.cs class.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct to get the /EditProduct page because that is the page you wanted to to access before being intercepted. what do you mean by "user click the Link of returnUrl at /AccessDenied page". The person is expected to login not to just click on some link. Put a  login form in the /AccessDenied page (if appropriate) or instead redirect to the /login page so the user can login and then be authenticated, else AllowAnonymous on the /EditProduct page (if appropriate) so it can be accessed unauthenticated.

Comment: Above mentioned pages are just example and not just real time scenario.
Let me explain the problem again. After Login, user is redirected to page1 becuase he passed authentication successfully but he is not authorized to see page2.
But when user tries to go page2 from page1, he is redirected to  AccessDenied page which show error message to user 'You are not authorized to see page2. Click here (link coming in returnUrl) to return to previous page'. Now the problem is,  page2 url is passed in returnUrl for which user is not authorized.
How to pass page1 url in retrunUrl.